# Handling ORA-01403: no data found

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to handle no data found. Whenever this exception is raised I want the program to continue, without stopping on error. Below is code snippet

```
BEGIN
  OPEN C_TABLE_PARTITON_LIST;
  LOOP
    FETCH C_TABLE_PARTITON_LIST INTO TABLE_PARTITION_LIST;
    EXIT WHEN C_TABLE_PARTITON_LIST%NOTFOUND;  
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME INTO PARTITION_COLUMN_NAME from ALL_PART_KEY_COLUMNS 
    sqlstring :='SELECT ( '|| PARTITION_COLUMN_NAME ||'from test';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstring INTO F_RESULT;  
    exception when no_data_found then
      dbms_output.put_line('no data found.');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( F_RESULT);

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C_TABLE_PARTITON_LIST;
END;
```

When I add Exception, my code is breaking with below error

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:
>     ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null
>      pragma raise return select update while with 
>        <<
>      continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
>      savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
>      json_exists json_value json_query json_object json_array
>   ORA-06550: line 29, column 3:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CLOSE" when expecting one of the following:
>      end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
>      member constructor map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enclose offending part of the script into its own BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END block, e.g.

```
BEGIN
  OPEN C_TABLE_PARTITON_LIST;
  LOOP
    FETCH C_TABLE_PARTITON_LIST INTO TABLE_PARTITION_LIST;
    EXIT WHEN C_TABLE_PARTITON_LIST%NOTFOUND;  

    begin     --> you need this ...

      SELECT COLUMN_NAME INTO PARTITION_COLUMN_NAME from ALL_PART_KEY_COLUMNS 
      sqlstring :='SELECT ( '|| PARTITION_COLUMN_NAME ||'from test';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstring INTO F_RESULT;  
    exception when no_data_found then
      dbms_output.put_line('no data found.');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( F_RESULT);

    end;      --> ... and this

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C_TABLE_PARTITON_LIST;
END;
```

Note that I just showed the way to do that. Code you posted

- is incomplete (misses the DECLARE section)
- is invalid (`SELECT` statement lacks semi-colon, and probably a `WHERE` clause
- `SQLSTRING` variable won't work; `'from test'` should have a leading space, otherwise that statement will be invalid
- I suggest you first `DBMS_OUTPUT` the `SQLSTRING` to make sure it is correct; then execute it.

Comment: Thanks, Adding Being and End around Exception works.